# CLR generic method branching based on the type of the generic argument

Tags: c#, .net, generics, clr, generic-method

In `C#`, is it generally a bad practice to use a generic argument to modify the behaviour of a generic method?

In example:

```
class Foo { }
class Bar { }

void GenericMethod<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Foo))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("execute action for Foo");
    }

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Bar))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("execute action for Bar");
    }
}

void NonGenericMethod(Type type)
{
    if (type == typeof(Foo))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("execute action for Foo");
    }

    if (type == typeof(Bar))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("execute action for Bar");
    }
}
```

The performance differences aside, both methods will have the same effect.

What I wonder about is, whether or not it is a good idea to use the the generic argument to modify the behaviour of the method (to do branching). Could this be considered a side effect?

Comment: _The performance differences aside_ - what performance differences are there?

Comment: Assuming you can't use overloads (why not?), there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

Comment: You could have put that method on base class of both Square and Circle, so just use regular inheritance. Otherwise, there is not much difference.

Comment: @Evk The actual classes provided as example are not important for the question. The question is simply about the generic argument usage.

Comment: The generic version is a bit awkward to use considerung `T` can't be inferred. If you have to call `GenericMethod<Square>()`, you might as well just use `MethodForSquares()`.

Comment: You are writing code that is *not* generic.  It will fail miserably when you use, say, `GenericMethod<string>`. And the other tens of thousands of type arguments you can think of.  So this is just plain wrong, don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant The provided code is just for ilustration (not real world code). The question is: "Is it generally a bad practice to modify method behaviour based on a generic argument?"

Comment: @Python- yes,it is bad.Listen to Hans Passsant

Comment: _"is it generally a bad practice to use a generic argument to modify the behaviour of a generic method"_ -- the question is fundamentally "primarily opinion based" and so not appropriate for Stack Overflow. That said, for this particular question, expert opinions are reasonably uniform: the whole point of a generic method or type is to be able to write code that can handle arbitrary types without concerning itself with what those types are. As soon as you introduce logic that depends on the type, you should've made a non-generic overload for that type instead of conditionally checking the type

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about using a generic method is that you can further invoke other generic methods without using reflection:

```
void GenericMethod<T>()
{
     AnotherGenericMethod<T>();
}
```

The non generic method requires reflection to make the same call.